# Unity3D send audioclip through whatsapp\telegram\etc

Tags: unity-game-engine

How on Unity3D I can send audioclip through whatsapp\telegram\etc? Any assets or code?

I'm find only how to send a picture.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the audioclip as a .wav file. You can use this script:

https://gist.github.com/darktable/2317063

For android you need a [fileprovider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) then to share that wav.

And for ios you can use the [UIDocumentInteractionController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uidocumentinteractioncontroller) with a plugin, use @"public.audio" as UTI.